# How to use premake to specify a C++11 compilation?

Tags: c++11, premake

I have tried using the "**C++11**" `premake` flag, to get the GNU C++ compiler to do a C++11 compilation.

However, this flag is not recognized and I get the message "invalid flag".

The statement I used in the `premake` lua script is the following, at either the project or configuration level:

```
flags {"C++11"}
```

I am using `premake4` on Windows 10 through `MSYS`. The g++ version is 4.8.1 and supports C++11. (When I use `make` directly, I am passing the c++11 flag as a compilation option to the compiler and it works.)

How can I proceed to get a C++11 compilation using `premake`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have tried a few things and I have a solution. It works.

1) First, with `premake4`, the `flags {"C++11"}` statement doesn't appear to work. What I mean is, on `premake4`, the `C++11` flag isn't recognized. Note that the `flags` statements itself is valid on `premake4` but (apparently) not the `C++11` flag .

2) On `premake5`, the `flags` statement itself has been deprecated. So you can't use `flags {"C++11"}` on `premake5`. Instead, use the `cppdialect "C++11"` statement. I used it within the `configuration` blocks.

3) Now, you can issue the statement to create the `makefiles` using `premake5`. Eg:

```
premake5 --file=premake-lua-scriptname.lua gmake
```

4) Later, when you run the generated `makefiles`, you will find the binary created, by default, in the `bin` subdirectory subordinate to the dir containing the premake5 lua script. Take my suggestion and override this default to have it created in the same dir as the lua script. (I'll explain why below.) You override this default using the `targetdir` function, which can be issued at the project level. Eg:

```
targetdir "."
```

5) Note that the current (alpha12) release of `premake5` doesn't support the `clean` action. To invoke the `clean` action, you will have to use `premake4`. That's why I suggested creating the binary in the default dir. `premake4` then cleans it by default.

All this works. However, is there a better solution?

Comment: I think it is preferred practice to use `gmake2`, as the Makefile format will be a bit more modern that with `gmake`.

Answer (score 0):

For windows build you do not need to specify anything since the vs version implies support of the required standard, so `premake5.exe vs2012` or later ver enough.

For linux or macOS use

`buildoptions "-std=c++11"`

Comment: As @SSteven mentioned, premake5-alpha12+ use `cppdialect "C++11"`. However, C++20 is not supported yet, so in this particular case I had to use `buildoptions "--std=c++20"` (with two hyphens).

Comment: Just realized `-std=c++20` is perfectly fine, but you need 2 hyphens when using space `--std c++20`